# Apex5.0, how to make a checkbox readonly

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

i have below select statement, I want to amend it to make the checkbox READ-ONLY.
how is it possible to do that pls??

SELECT emp_id,
emp_name, 
emp_title, 
APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX(p_idx => 10, p_value => id , p_attributes => DECODE(status,'Y','checked="checked"', NULL)) status,
FROM emp_tbl WHERE emp_id = :P1_emp_id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what exact behaviour you want, you could try either

1) adding to the attribute (p_attributes): disabled

or

2) adding to the attribute (p_attributes): onclick="return false;"

Hope this is of some help.

Comment: when using the disabled its not working, can you please tell where to add it in the p_attributes => DECODE(status,'Y','checked="checked"', NULL)) status

Comment: Ive tried both solutions, but when clicked on null Chkbox, it gets ticked which shouldn't... any idea how to amend it?  the Chkbx should be uneditable if status is Y or null

Comment: You probably had a syntax issue.  But I see that @Amol has shown you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Include following change

```
 p_attributes => DECODE(status,'Y','checked="checked" onclick="return false;"', 'onclick="return false;"')
```

Hope this will help you !

Comment: it works but i want to make it uneditable even when checkbox is null how to do that?

Comment: please check updated answer..Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'readonly=readonly' property in check box.
Kindly check the case from Google  as this is case sensitive.

Regards,
Nikita